# ClassName of annonymous inner class is same - obj.getClass().getName()

Tags: java, lambda, foreach, java-8, inner-classes

I am creating 20 new new inner classes and overriden a method to print the class name. But everytime i am getting those 20 instances the class name is the same. My requirement is to get different class names for each of them. How can I achieve this? Any pointers are much appreciated - thank you.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class TestClassName {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


    List<? super Check>  list=   IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 20).mapToObj(e -> new Check() {

        @Override
        public void execute() {
            System.out.println(this.getClass().getName());

        }
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());

list.forEach(i -> ((Check)i).execute());
}
}

interface Check {
public abstract void execute();
}
```

## Output

```
TestClassName$2
TestClassName$2
TestClassName$2
TestClassName$2
TestClassName$2
TestClassName$2
TestClassName$2
TestClassName$2
TestClassName$2
TestClassName$2
TestClassName$2
TestClassName$2
TestClassName$2
TestClassName$2
TestClassName$2
TestClassName$2
TestClassName$2
TestClassName$2
TestClassName$2
    TestClassName$2
```

Comment: You're just creating new instances of the same anonymous class. You can't create new class names at run time (at least not easily). What's the use case you have in mind for this? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have a registry service expose to the outside clients that can register their services mulitple times for certain node type , so clients can create as  many number of objects and can register for the same node type again and again. I wanna avoid executing same objects by filtering through their class Name.

Comment: All objects of a certain type will have the *same* class name. You might need to have some (unique) identifier for identifying each registration.

Comment: Why not just use `==` to test object identity? Or use some sort of hash-based collection type for the registry, if you want to use `equals()` to distinguish between objects. (Note that `equals()` is the same as `==` unless your objects override the default behavior.)

Comment: Yup i thought of it but what if clients are too impatient to implement proper hashcode() , equals() ?? I mean they can implement them wrongly causing error behavior of object identity and hashing to store in hash based collections

Comment: I think it is reasonable to base the design on proper implementations of basic Object methods.  This is the requirement of using many Java collections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple: you are instantiating the *same* inner class repeatedly.

Your code only contains one inner class!

When you would do *new Integer()* 20 times, would you assume that creates a new Integer class each time? Of course not. The class stays the same, you just get different objects of the same class.

In order to have multiple anonymous inner classes created, you have to actually add the definitions repeatedly in the source code!

To solve your problem, you need a registry that uses the "identity" of objects, not their class!

Answer (score 1):

You're just creating new instances of the same anonymous class. It's very difficult (or perhaps impossible, depending on what security manager is installed) to add new classes at run time. And it's almost surely not what you need to do.

From the comments to your question, it seems like you simply need to distinguish between instances of your interface. For that, the simplest would be to use a hash map in your registry.

Most map implementations (like `HashMap`) rely on so-called *value equality*: the map treats two references as the same object if `equals()` returns `true`. In some cases (and I don't know if yours is one of them), this is not the right semantics, and you need object identity (that is, two references are treated as the same only if they are `==`). For that, you can use `IdentityHashMap` instead of `HashMap` inside your registry. It uses `System.identityHashCode()` and `==` to implement the map and doesn't use an object's implementation of `equals()` or `hashCode()`.

In your comments you indicated a concern about whether clients implement `equals()` and `hashcode()` correctly. This strikes me as borrowing trouble, but if you want to deal with that, `IdentityHashMap` will do the job here as well. Alternatively, you could replace your interface with an abstract base class that implements `equals()` and `hashCode()` as `final` methods that delegate to their `Object` implementations, but this seems heavy-handed and perhaps not workable.